# Select an XML element regardless of level with XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <t>text</t>
  </b>
</a>
<a>
  <t>text</t>
</a>
```

So I want to select the text regardless of where is it.
(note that it can be anywhere not just 1/2 levels down, it can have no parents for instance)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are looking for [the `descendant` axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes):

> the `descendant` axis contains the descendants of the context node; a
>   descendant is a child or a child of a
>   child and so on; thus the descendant
>   axis never contains attribute or
>   namespace nodes

In your case: `/descendant:t`

Of course, as others have answered, [there is an abbreviated syntax for this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. For
>   example, `//para` is short for
>   `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para`
>   and so will select any `para` element
>   in the document (even a `para` element
>   that is a document element will be
>   selected by `//para` since the
>   document element node is a child of
>   the root node)

Answer (score 29):

You can use `//` to select all nodes from the current node. So `//text()` would select all text nodes.

If you wanted all t elements you would do `//t`. If you wanted to do do all `t` elements from a certain point you might then do `/x/y//t`.

Answer (score 10):

just `//t` if you want all `<t>` tags

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools has really good free courses regarding everything that is HTML related.
I highly recommend reading it and making the examples.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

**HINT**: you can use your browser's console to evalute expressions. It's under Developer Tools - F12 key for Chorme and Firefox:

```
$x('<your expressions>');
```

So, as everyone said, you can use the `//` syntax to find an element anywhere in the page.
e.g. `//a` will return you **all** `a` elements within the page.

Most likely you will want a specific one, so, that's where you use the predicates. They are contained between brackets.
Using this very page as example, here is a xquery:

```
//a[text()="Simeon"]
```

This xpath will return all `a` elements that have Simeon as it's text.
In many situations you might need to improve you xpath to include more identifiers, be more specific.

```
//a[text()="Simeon" AND @href="/users/274344/simeon"]
```

So, you can use pretty much any HTML attribute, or even CSS to identify a specific node you want.

But now, let´s take it up a notch.
Let´s say you want to get the `a` element that is below user's **mkimd** answer from **Jan 27**.
If you look at this page structure, you have to get you `a` and dive back a few levels, untill you are able to reach the **span** that holds the posting date.

```
//a[text()="mkimd" AND ../../div[@class="user-action-time"]/span[contains(.,"Jan")]]
```

There are many ways of doing these queries,this last example I gave can be achieved with different xqueries.

I find that xqueries are very similar to navigation in directories in console, like Linux BASH - relative and absolute paths, and the identifiers are like `SQL WHERE` clauses.

If you research, there are many functions available in XPATH syntax, such as

- lower-case()
- upper-case()
- concat()
- ends-with()
- operators ( `+`,`-`,`*`,`div`,`!=`,`<`,`<=`,`>`, ...)

I highly advise you to use some tool like **Firefox Firefug FirePath** addon to practice xquery and check if you are getting the element you want - it highlights the elements found.

====================

EDIT - May-8th-15

In case you are using Xpath in Selenium automation, know that it will not help you select CSS pseudo elements.

Comment: I feel strongly inclined to point out that nobody should consider W3schools a good source for any information. Their information is sometimes incorrect, inaccurate, or outdated, or a combination of these things. When possible, always use another source, such as Mozilla developer network. For many things pertaining to Xpath and XSLT, StackOverflow, especially Dmitri Novachev's answers are a preferable source of information, which is subject to more error checking.

Comment: @Joeppie I take your point, I thought they were related to W3C, they are not. Anyhow, I learned almost all I needed related to XPATHs and CSS in their website, with support of StackOverflow and other websites for sure. I like their website because they provide tools to learn on the website itself, in your browser.

Comment: Hmm, it could very well be that it has become a better source of information now. I once pointed out a mistake in their JavaScript example pertaining to the "for" loop, and they did address that; if they have done this for many things and added in-website tools, then their quality of information is likely to have increased significantly since I last checked.